# I am having error "can't import main" in using Python pip to install Pyhook

Tags: python, pip, pyhook

I am trying to install pyhook by using Pip in python,

but everytime it gives error of can't import main.

```
pip3.6 install Pyhook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main**strong text**
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "F:\Python\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip3.6.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Comment: Running through other forums, a lot of people having same issue, some reports uninstalling pip and installing it back again seems to work for majority, or maybe even upgrading it? What pip are you running?

Comment: `python -m pip install PyHook` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install pyHook package "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895493/cant-install-pyhook-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requir)