# Can't install pyHook package "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook"

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.7, pyhook

im trying to install the `pyHook` package in `pycharm` but get the error in the title. I have successfully installed it in cmd with `pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` ,but when I go to install it in pycharm I get the `aforementioned` error :

> **Collecting pyHook Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyHook**

Comment: What error did you get ? please write logs detail

Comment: Collecting pyHook

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyHook

Comment: this file is for 3.7 (cp3.7) - maybe PyCharm uses different Python's version? Did you try to install directly from server `pip install pyHook` ? If you know path to Python used by PyCharm then you can use this Python in `cmd`

Comment: pycharm is using 3.7 and I installed with pip install pyHook and it says requirement already satisfied in cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem myself, and after alot of searching, found that although pyhook has wheels for python 3, it's incompatible. Look at the last release date for pyhook: October 10th 2008. Python 3 was released in: December 3rd 2008.

I would suggest that you look into the keyboard module. It supports python 3, and has all of the functions of pyhook as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by fixing the package version: PyUserInput==0.1.10